# Cómo detectar un radiobutton si esta seleccionado y que al estar seleccionado cambiar clase de un div

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema y es que necesito que cuando seleccione un *radio button* cambie la clase de un `<div>` por otra

```js
function mostrarSeleccionado() {
  if (document.getElementById("lunes").checked) {
    Document.getElementById("contenedorLunes").classname =
      "contenedorLunesMostrar";
    console.log("detectado");
  } else if (document.getElementById("martes").checked) {
  } else if (document.getElementById("miercoles").checked) {
  } else if (document.getElementById("jueves").checked) {
  } else if (document.getElementById("viernes").checked) {
  } else if (document.getElementById("sabado").checked) {
  } else if (document.getElementById("domingo").checked) {
  }
}
```

```css
#planActivate {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}

.guia {
  padding: 200px;
}
.negrita {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.letra {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.botonIniciar {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  background: rgb(29, 29, 73);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 15px;
}
.fecha {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.contadorSemana {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.semana {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 100px;
}
.Principal {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 15px;
  border: solid 2px #012e58;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: #012e58;
}
.botonDia input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.botonDia input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #012e58;
  padding: 50px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: #fff;
}

.contenedorLunes {
  display: none;
}
.contenedorLunesMostrar {
  display: block;
}
.gridVideos {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}
.video1,
.video2,
.video3 {
  text-align: center;
}
.video {
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/activate.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="planActivate">
    <p>
      ¡Bienvenido a tu plan de actividad física! A través de este, tendrás diferentes guías para volver el ejercicio
      un hábito de vida a favor de tu salud y bienestar integral.
    </p>

    <p>Para empezar, es importante que puedas informarte sobre las siguientes recomendaciones mínimas para
      que tu paso del sedentarismo a la actividad física regular sea saludable y sin lesiones o contratiempos de
      ningún tipo.</p>

    <div class="guia">
      <p>espacio en blanco (falta información) </p>
    </div>

    <div class="Reto">
      <p> <span class="negrita letra">Reto 4 semanas</span> </p>
      <p>¡Es momento de empezar a activarte! En el siguiente reto, encontrarás una rutina de ejercicios diaria
        durante un mes para ponerte en sintonía con el cambio de hábitos que deseas y pasar del sedentarismo a
        la acción, con la guía de nuestros expertos.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Iniciar">
      <p>Selecciona la fecha de inicio:</p>
      <input class="fecha" type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha">
      <a href="#" class="botonIniciar">Iniciar</a>
    </div>
    <div class="contadorSemana">
      <p class="negrita">Semana 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="semana">
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="lunes" />
        <label for="lunes" class="Principal">Lunes </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="martes" />
        <label for="martes" class="Principal">Martes </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="miercoles" />
        <label for="miercoles" class="Principal">Miercoles </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="jueves" />
        <label for="jueves" class="Principal">Jueves </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="viernes" />
        <label for="viernes" class="Principal">Viernes </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="sabado" />
        <label for="sabado" class="Principal">Sábado </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="domingo" />
        <label for="domingo" class="Principal">Domingo </label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="contenedorLunes" id="contenedorLunes">
      <div class="texto">
        <p>¡Feliz día! Para el entrenamiento de
          hoy vas a necesitar:</p>
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="videos">
        <div class="gridVideos">
          <div class="video1">
            <p>Calentamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video2">
            <p>Entrenamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video3">
            <p>Calentamiento</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/Activate.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [`Element.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), para que el navegador ejecute algo cuando tu `radio button` cambie.

Por otro lado, veo que en todos tus `<label>` tienes la clase *Principal*, por lo que no es necesario obtenerlos uno por uno para cambiar la clase, ya que puedes quedarte con el [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

Usando el punto anterior a nuestro favor, podemos crear un selector CSS para usar [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Un selector tal que así

```
input + label.Principal
```

De esta manera obtendremos todos los elementos `<label>` para saber a qué día nos referimos, ya que el `<label>` tiene el día en su contenido y obtendremos el `radio`

Podemos usar [`Node.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) y [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes), el primero para obtener el nodo padre del `radio` (el `<div>`) y el segundo para obtener los nodos hijos del primero, es decir que obtendremos el `radio` y el `<label>`

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input + label.Principal").forEach(e => {
  const radio = e.parentNode.children[0];
  const dia = e.textContent.trim();
  radio.addEventListener("input", () => {
    // ¿Tienes más contenedores como contenedorMartes?
    // ¿O solo se usa contenedorLunes?
    document.getElementById("contenedorLunes").classname =
      "contenedor"+dia+"Mostrar";
    console.log("detectado", dia);
  });
});
```

```css
#planActivate {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}

.guia {
  padding: 200px;
}
.negrita {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.letra {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.botonIniciar {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  background: rgb(29, 29, 73);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 15px;
}
.fecha {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.contadorSemana {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.semana {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 100px;
}
.Principal {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 15px;
  border: solid 2px #012e58;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: #012e58;
}
.botonDia input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.botonDia input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #012e58;
  padding: 50px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: #fff;
}

.contenedorLunes {
  display: none;
}
.contenedorLunesMostrar {
  display: block;
}
.gridVideos {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}
.video1,
.video2,
.video3 {
  text-align: center;
}
.video {
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/activate.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="planActivate">
    <p>
      ¡Bienvenido a tu plan de actividad física! A través de este, tendrás diferentes guías para volver el ejercicio
      un hábito de vida a favor de tu salud y bienestar integral.
    </p>

    <p>Para empezar, es importante que puedas informarte sobre las siguientes recomendaciones mínimas para
      que tu paso del sedentarismo a la actividad física regular sea saludable y sin lesiones o contratiempos de
      ningún tipo.</p>

    <div class="guia">
      <p>espacio en blanco (falta información) </p>
    </div>

    <div class="Reto">
      <p> <span class="negrita letra">Reto 4 semanas</span> </p>
      <p>¡Es momento de empezar a activarte! En el siguiente reto, encontrarás una rutina de ejercicios diaria
        durante un mes para ponerte en sintonía con el cambio de hábitos que deseas y pasar del sedentarismo a
        la acción, con la guía de nuestros expertos.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Iniciar">
      <p>Selecciona la fecha de inicio:</p>
      <input class="fecha" type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha">
      <a href="#" class="botonIniciar">Iniciar</a>
    </div>
    <div class="contadorSemana">
      <p class="negrita">Semana 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="semana">
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="lunes" />
        <label for="lunes" class="Principal">Lunes </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="martes" />
        <label for="martes" class="Principal">Martes </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="miercoles" />
        <label for="miercoles" class="Principal">Miercoles </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="jueves" />
        <label for="jueves" class="Principal">Jueves </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="viernes" />
        <label for="viernes" class="Principal">Viernes </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="sabado" />
        <label for="sabado" class="Principal">Sábado </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="domingo" />
        <label for="domingo" class="Principal">Domingo </label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="contenedorLunes" id="contenedorLunes">
      <div class="texto">
        <p>¡Feliz día! Para el entrenamiento de
          hoy vas a necesitar:</p>
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="videos">
        <div class="gridVideos">
          <div class="video1">
            <p>Calentamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video2">
            <p>Entrenamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video3">
            <p>Calentamiento</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/Activate.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: entiendo tu punto, gracias por compartirlo, pero no se si estoy haciendo algo mal pero no al presionar el imput "lunes" no me cambia la clase del div "contenedorLunes" por "contenedorLunesMostrar", habrian un div por cada dia de la semana el cual si le doy click en el dia se deberia mostrar solamente ese div mediante el cambio de nombre de la clase ej: "contenedorLunesMostrar", "contenedorMartesMostrar"